Text generation using LLM based on some key words stored in a CSV
I want to generate text using a model along with prompt and other parameters. How do I use context-data / supporting data present in a CSV file so that the LLM can generate text content based on the contextual inputs present in that CSV file.
llm = ChatVertexI(model="gemini-pro",temperature=0)

response = llm.invoke("how can langsmith help with testing?")

How to pass the context data that is present in the code snippet?
I have to pass that data so that model is able to generate the text for a writeup based on the context data (list of key topics / sections in a CSV tabular format to build the text
output as per this context)
I will really appreciate if a sample code block end-t-end is shared so that I can build on top of it for my use-case
